# Altering a Table with pymysql

Tags: python, alter, pymysql

I'm new to pymysql and I'm working with an existing database and I was wondering how I could edit an existing table to add a new column. What I am currently trying is:

```
query="""ALTER TABLE feel_eda ADD sleeptime INT"""
self.safe_execute(query)
```

the code for safe_execute is:

```
def safe_execute(self, query):
  try: 
      #print 'task id: '+ str(tornado.process.task_id())
      q_str  = (query[:150] + '..') if len(query) > 150 else query
      #print "executing query; {0}.".format(q_str)
      self.cursor.execute(query)
      return True
  except Exception as ex:
      print ex.args[0]
      return False
```

Which returns False so I want to know what's wrong with my query?

Comment: First of all you can import `traceback` and call `traceback.print_exc()` in the `except` block to get a more detailed error message

Comment: do you have any particular reason to use pymysql? just curious. And please, post the error message.

Comment: I'm using pymysql because I am working on someone's existing web application and their code uses pymysql.

Comment: The error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/george/FEELv2/feel_base.py", line 49, in safe_execute
    self.cursor.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 117, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 189, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue

Comment: ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0' at line 3")

Comment: it appears there was a problem in my syntax would anyone happen to know the appropriate syntax for adding a column to a table in pymysql?